# PHP detect Opera

Tags: php, drupal, browser-detection

How can I detect Opera with PHP? Im using lightbox with drupal and their is a bug in opera, so if the site is being viewed with opera I want to print a normal link instead of the lightbox.

I found this link but it just says 'other browser' not opera: 
http://drupal.org/node/65903

This prints the browser being used and seems to work fine:

```
<?php echo $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']; ?>
```

So can I modify the code to print something if the browser is opera? If so, are their any pit falls to this method?

Thanks

Comment: Why not just fix the bug rather than have special server-side browser support?

Comment: You could fix that code by replacing `strpos` with `strstr` - in particular for the Opera if.

Comment: I've never used it, but you could try [`get_browser()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-browser.php).

Comment: I wouldn't know where to begin to fix the bug and it seems a lot of people have tried and failed. @mario can you give me some more information on your method? Here is the issue on drupal: http://drupal.org/node/754348

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try using http://chrisschuld.com/projects/browser-php-detecting-a-users-browser-from-php/, it looks like an useful script, however, if that PHP code you entered is echoing something you can use to change how the link is rendered, then that might be fine. The only thing is that you should use a some loose string comparison, not a strict one, because Opera's user agents might change between versions or operating systems.

Comment: I found that link but it seem overkill for me. I just need to detect all versions of Opera, as most people are using the latest one. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Check [this link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-browser.php). Down in the comments, somebody posted the following code:

```
<?php
function getBrowser() 
{ 
    $u_agent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']; 
    $bname = 'Unknown';
    $platform = 'Unknown';
    $version= "";

    //First get the platform?
    if (preg_match('/linux/i', $u_agent)) {
        $platform = 'linux';
    }
    elseif (preg_match('/macintosh|mac os x/i', $u_agent)) {
        $platform = 'mac';
    }
    elseif (preg_match('/windows|win32/i', $u_agent)) {
        $platform = 'windows';
    }

    // Next get the name of the useragent yes seperately and for good reason
    if(preg_match('/MSIE/i',$u_agent) && !preg_match('/Opera/i',$u_agent)) 
    { 
        $bname = 'Internet Explorer'; 
        $ub = "MSIE"; 
    } 
    elseif(preg_match('/Firefox/i',$u_agent)) 
    { 
        $bname = 'Mozilla Firefox'; 
        $ub = "Firefox"; 
    } 
    elseif(preg_match('/Chrome/i',$u_agent)) 
    { 
        $bname = 'Google Chrome'; 
        $ub = "Chrome"; 
    } 
    elseif(preg_match('/Safari/i',$u_agent)) 
    { 
        $bname = 'Apple Safari'; 
        $ub = "Safari"; 
    } 
    elseif(preg_match('/Opera/i',$u_agent)) 
    { 
        $bname = 'Opera'; 
        $ub = "Opera"; 
    } 
    elseif(preg_match('/Netscape/i',$u_agent)) 
    { 
        $bname = 'Netscape'; 
        $ub = "Netscape"; 
    } 

    // finally get the correct version number
    $known = array('Version', $ub, 'other');
    $pattern = '#(?<browser>' . join('|', $known) .
    ')[/ ]+(?<version>[0-9.|a-zA-Z.]*)#';
    if (!preg_match_all($pattern, $u_agent, $matches)) {
        // we have no matching number just continue
    }

    // see how many we have
    $i = count($matches['browser']);
    if ($i != 1) {
        //we will have two since we are not using 'other' argument yet
        //see if version is before or after the name
        if (strripos($u_agent,"Version") < strripos($u_agent,$ub)){
            $version= $matches['version'][0];
        }
        else {
            $version= $matches['version'][1];
        }
    }
    else {
        $version= $matches['version'][0];
    }

    // check if we have a number
    if ($version==null || $version=="") {$version="?";}

    return array(
        'userAgent' => $u_agent,
        'name'      => $bname,
        'version'   => $version,
        'platform'  => $platform,
        'pattern'    => $pattern
    );
} 
?>
```

So you could say something like:

```
$browser = getBrowser();
if($browser['name'] == "Opera")
{
    echo "This is opera!";
}
```

Comment: If I copy and paste the code as it is the code is shown on the page as text. If I add opening and closing php tags then the page gets screwed up in any browser. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can modify the code.  Just use what Opera is giving you for `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']` to make the right change.

As far as pitfalls go, remember that people can change their user agent.  Some applications will change your browser's user agent as well.  So user agent sniffing isn't a surefire way to guarantee compatibility ... in reality, you'd be better checking for specific browser capabilities *on the front end* rather than checking on the server side.  But if you're stuck doing this in PHP, you're on the right track.

Comment: Sorry for the newbie question but how exactly can I write that php as conditional to print something? Thanks

Comment: `<?php if(condition) { echo 'thing you want to print'; } ?>`

Comment: In that case do you know why TheAdamGaskins method doesn't work? Thanks